# why does hibernate not force you to mark fields as virtual, but nhibernate does?

Tags: java, nhibernate, hibernate

why does hibernate not force you to mark fields as virtual, but nhibernate does?

Is this a result of the differences between the VM and CLR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a difference between *runtimes* - it's a difference between *languages*.

In C#, methods aren't virtual by default. In Java, they are.

Note that neither platform allows *fields* to be virtual, as described in your question.

Hibernate and NHibernate both require virtual methods - which means making them *explicitly* virtual in C#.

(Note that in Java the terminology "virtual method" isn't actually defined in the language specification; here I'm using it to mean "non-final": a method which can be overridden.)

Comment: @Willi: Which bit sounds extremely strange?

Answer (score 2):

In Java all methods are by default virtual. In .NET you need to explicitly mark a method as virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Because the default behaviour in Java is for methods to be overridable unless the `final` keyword is specified, whereas in .NET it is for methods to be non-overridable unless the `virtual` keyword is specified.

Comment: Not fields - fields can't be overridden at all in either environment.